# Insert HTML line breaks in jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a "posting" system and I wanted to incorporate jQuery into it so that it's more smooth an the page doesn't have to refresh.

I ran into some problems with it. When the user types a line break in the text area, the jQuery returns "n" instead of a line break.

I send the *post* data to a PHP script and it adds the value into the database. If it is successful it will print out HTML that the *post* is in. HTML is prepended into a  in the main PHP page.

I tried adding an nl2br on the PHP that processes the post but that didn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

**Here's the code:**
JQuery:

```
function submit_post(){
var post = $('#textarea').val();
$.('post', { post: post }, function(result){
//if PHP returns an error do something
else{
$('#divname').prepend(result);
}
```

PHP:

```
//PHP processes the user's post
$post = nl2br(stripslashes($post));
//print html formats the post
echo $post;
//html ends
```

I hope this is enough information to have the question answered. If not I'd be happy to supply you with more code and information.

Comment: You are asking how to learn about a bad practice :)

Comment: Any suggestions? I know my method isn't the most efficient but I'm always open to new ideas and ways of doing this. :)

Comment: That would be a more useful comment if it discussed why updating that way is a bad practice.

Comment: @JoeC. for you clarifiction only :) **Speration of concerns** . Why is it bad to have inline CSS or Javascript in HTML? Just line that it is bad to HTML in things which are not HTML.

Comment: It's bad to have inline CSS because the point of CSS is to separate presentation from content. Javascript is separate because the browser goes on coffee break whenever it encounters a JS block. But if you want a dynamic page, the only way to get it is to use JS to load the appropriate content (that's pretty much the entire reason for AJAX). Or possibly an IFrame, but that certainly isn't a cleaner method of doing this. And there are plenty of reasons to use dynamic content.

Comment: @JoeC. please use nick with `@` symbol when replying. I did not know you have replied. Any way what you are saying is senseless accept for browser bit . Ajax has nothing to do with `"inline"` html neither has `iframe` . OP is aksing how he can insert `HTML` line break. There is not need (with super rare excepting may be) that he should be doing that. Yes no one can stop you for writing hacky code in the name of perfromance but a good design will not need to break ** Separation of concerns** .

Comment: @Shahzeb: You learn something new every day. I wasn't aware of the `@` symbol convention on StackOverflow. No, Ajax has nothing to do with inline CSS nor with iframes, and I'm not sure how my statements can be interpreted as saying so. I was merely addressing your examples, and explaining why they're widely considered bad practice. The part about Ajax (and iframes) was purely in reference to having dynamic content, which it seemed like your comment was labeling 'bad practice' (a concept which I've never encountered before). Dynamic content doesn't itself break separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a string replec method.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Use it to search for all the new line characters ("\n") and replace it with <br>.

Addon:

do a loop

```
while(string.search("\n")) {
    string.replace("\n", "<br>");
}
```

Comment: This works fine with one but then when I try to find all of them it stops working I tried .replace(/\n/gi, "<br>"); like it said but it doesn't work...

Comment: Dan: what doesn't that(`.replace(/\n/gi, "<br>"`)) work? It works for me.

Comment: @Dan. So what is the output when you used ".replace(/\n/gi, "<br>")"?